# Excel 2013 - need age that is input to reference numerical value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am creating a spreadsheet of insurance rates from a number of companies. I would like to input the age of the individual once, which would then populate figures for each of the companies, retrieving data specific to each insurer.

Example: John is 27 years old and I want to show figures for a dozen different companies, each of which has a different rate. I input John's age into a cell, and figures for each company are then populated into the spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet we have now requires each rate to be manually input.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

TIA-

Kevin

Comment: Are the rates different based on the age? Do you have tables of rates for each company based on the age?

Comment: Rates are based on age, and each company has their own rate. Tables of rates for each company will be input on another page in the spreadsheet.

Comment: does the below resolve your problem or did I overlook any constraints?

Comment: I think this will resolve our needs, however because I am not familiar with using this command I will need to work with the example you provided. And I am assuming that we can have tables for each company on a separate sheet from the illustration, correct?  Thanks, Petr

Comment: Yes, you can have the tables on different sheets, just update the formula to reference them correctly. If you decide to go with named ranges then update the names. If everything works out, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be using VLOOKUP to lookup the rates for the insurance companies. You may also employ named ranges with INDIRECT to simply drag the formula across.

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?page=view&resid=D91C36B074F4D0F6!3201&authkey=!AJGburNS2D5-0jc) is the sample file I came up with

[image: Insurance rates]